# Empty Ubuntu Unity Dash after upgrade to 19.10 and search doesn't do anything

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I just updated to Ubuntu 19.10 using the software updater and now the Ubuntu Unity Dash is empty and I cannot run any programs apart from those in the side panel.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue and noticed that the unity-lens-* packages were removed for some reason, so do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-*
```

Comment: asterix wasnt doing it on 19.10 so: sudo apt install unity-lens-files unity-lens-applications unity-lens-video unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos with a reboot sorted it out

Comment: Reboot is not needed. Simply logut from the session and login again to reload the desktop.

Comment: @SauliusM That's because you used apt instead of apt-get. :)

Comment: Need to log out and in. Just `unity --replace` doesn't work.