# Super + search not working after upgrade to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, search, 19.10

I upgraded to 19.10 yesterday. Now, when I hit <kbd>Super</kbd> and start typing the name of a bit of software, no results are coming up in the search results area below the search box. But if I know the exact name of what I'm trying to open and I type it in full, it opens.

[image: Screenshot showing no search results]

Previously, if, say, I wanted GIMP and I pressed <kbd>Super</kbd> and typed "GI", I used to get search results for "GI...", but now I get a blank screen underneath the search box. If I do press <kbd>Super</kbd>, type "GIMP" and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, it opens GIMP.

*Tweaks* → *Extensions* → *User Themes* is ON.

Comment: Happening since I upgraded to 19.10 yesterday.  Logouts and reboots have made no difference.

Comment: Similar question posted today: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188277/search-computer-function-not-working-on-upgrade-from-19-04-to-19-10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty Ubuntu Dash after upgrade to 19.10 and search doesn't do anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182199/empty-ubuntu-dash-after-upgrade-to-19-10-and-search-doesnt-do-anything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced the same issue after updating to Ubuntu 19.10.

The following was able to solve it for me:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install yaru-theme-gnome-shell
```

Followed by a reboot.

I also disabled shell extensions prior to that but I'm not sure if that was necessary

I had at some point installed the yaru colors theme and my thought is that didn't play well with the update, removing the theme alone wasn't enough and I had to re-install the default yaru theme provided with Ubuntu.

Comment: I've disabled all extensions and still have this.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue persists in spite of trying all other solutions, check which is your login session (cogwheel button in login screen).

I had an outdated package of "Ubuntu Communitheme", but switching to "Ubuntu (Wayland)" or "Gnome" or "Gnome (Xorg)" solved it (but interestingly not the default Ubuntu without Wayland).