# Search computer function not working on upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, 19.10

After upgrading to 19.10 from 19.04 search function does not work.
No results are displayed no matter what is entered.

Same question as this, didn't want to hijack the question:
[Search functionality not happening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187537/search-functionality-not-happening)

Possibly the same as [Super + search not working after upgrade to 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186363/super-search-not-working-after-upgrade-to-19-10).

I did not try the answer yet:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install yaru-theme-gnome-shell
```

No changes were made, simple upgrade.

[image: What happened. Nothing!]

Comment: Why didn't you try the suggested solution? The command you mention will not harm your system in any way. It will just reinstall the package 'yaru-theme-gnome-shell'.

Comment: Not exactly the same issue.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? If so try disabling them to see if normal behavior is restored.

Comment: Nothing installed that I recall, pretty basic usage. How to see installed extensions?

Comment: Are you using the `yaru` theme? If so I wonder if changing to the default theme (like the developers probably tend to use) would be successful?

Comment: To list your extensions see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133782/command-to-list-installed-and-enabled-gnome-extensions

Comment: pw@pw-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
ls: cannot access '/home/pw/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/': No such file or directory    Also I have no knowledge of yaru so not installed I think.

Answer (score 0):

I did try the suggested solution above to no avail.
As a workaround for the problem I launched "Software" which was locked to the Launcher and in "Installed" I launched "Application Finder" which apparently is installed by default. I locked it to the launcher and keep it open on the desktop.

Hope this might help others.