# Unity Dash not showing Applications after upgrade from 19.04 to 20.04

Tags: unity, 20.04, unity-dash

I'm a longtime Ubuntu (and Unity) user (12+ years).

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 19.04 to 20.04, which I had to do because 19.04 was retired and everything was working perfectly, but when I logged back in... the unity dash cannot find any applications.

I have spent about 10 hours already Googling and trying everything I can find, including:

- `rm ~/.cache/software-center -R`
- Installing some packages with `zeitgest` in the name.
- Installing, reinstalling, purging packages with `unity-lens-something`.
- Validating .desktop files with `desktop-file-validate`

This last thing (`desktop-file-validate`) does give me quite a few warnings in the `/usr/share/applications/` folder. However, I have tried moving that folder and creating an empty version of it (or with one correct .desktop file) and it still does not bring my apps back.

I'm under a tight work schedule as a coder who works remotely and I reaaaaallly cannot deal with this right now, since I'm more busy trying to stay employed. I can't even use the default Ubuntu desktop effectively since it won't let me change the screen resolution when I'm in there.

I had everything configured so well to be productive for so many years before this happened!

Any help with this will truly be appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I didn't give enough detail: I updated to 19.10 first and then to 20.04. Can you help me with my problem, though?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty Ubuntu Unity Dash after upgrade to 19.10 and search doesn't do anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182199/empty-ubuntu-unity-dash-after-upgrade-to-19-10-and-search-doesnt-do-anything)

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. A temporary fix is to logout, change the environment from Unity to Gnome or something else and login. Gnome has a dropdown application menu that lists everything. I haven't found the solution for Unity yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It seems that Ubuntu lens is removed during the upgrade. You need to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-*
```

and restart. Also check this thread [Empty Ubuntu Unity Dash after upgrade to 19.10 and search doesn't do anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182199/empty-ubuntu-unity-dash-after-upgrade-to-19-10-and-search-doesnt-do-anything)

Comment: Seems they are all installed already in my case: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.`